# Stack calculator

Tags: c++, stack

I found this code online so I could study stack calculators, but when I try to enter an expression for the program to evaluate, it gives me 78. Every time. I've combed through it to see if I could debug it by myself, but I have no clue how to fix this. I've added the comments myself to make things more readable. Could anyone help?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int pri(char ch) //precedence checking
{
  switch (ch)
  {
    case '-':
    case '+': return 1;
    case '*':
    case '/': return 2;
    case '^': return 3;
    case '(': 
    case ')': return 4;
    default: return -1;
    }
}


int calculate(char op, int l , int r) //actual calculations
{
  if(op == '+') return l + r;
  
  if(op == '-') return l - r ;
   
  if(op == '*') return l * r;
   
  if(op == '/')
   {
       if(r > 0)
       {
          return l/r;
       }
       return 0;
    }
  if(op == '^') return pow(l,r);
  
  return -1;
}


int main(void)
{
  string equ;
  cout << "Enter an expression: ";
  getline(cin, equ);
  char math[equ.size()+1];
  int l = sizeof(math)/sizeof(char);
  stack<char> s;
  stack<int> op_s;
  int i = 0;
  
  while(math[i] != '\0')
  { 
    if(math[i] == '(')
    {
      s.push('(');
      }
    else if(math[i] == ')')
    {
      while(s.top() != '(')
      {
        int r = op_s.top();
        op_s.pop();
        int l = op_s.top();
        op_s.pop();
        int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
        op_s.push(re);
        s.pop();
        }
      s.pop();
     }
     else if(math[i] == '+' || math[i] == '-' || math[i] == '*' || math[i] == '/' || math[i] == '^')
     {
        int pC = pri(math[i]);
        while(!s.empty() && pri(s.top()) >= pC)
        {
          int r = op_s.top();
          op_s.pop();
          int l = op_s.top();
          op_s.pop();
          int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
          op_s.push(re);
          s.pop();
          }
           s.push(math[i]);
       }
       else
       {
          op_s.push(int(math[i])- 48);
       }
      i++;
   }
   while(!s.empty())
   {
       int r = op_s.top();
       op_s.pop();
       int l = op_s.top();
       op_s.pop();
       int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
       op_s.push(re);
       s.pop();
   }

   cout <<"Result: " << op_s.top() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char math[equ.size()+1];` defines a variable-length array which is not supported by the C++ standard.  Regarding your question, what expression do you enter?  Do you enter the _same_ expression every time?  Telling us your program outputs 78 every time is pointless without telling us what you put into it.

Comment: One handy trick for debugging code like this is to replace the call to `getline` with an assignment: `equ = “whatever”:`. That gives you a consistent formula to test with, and it gives you something you can post here.

Comment: @paddy when I first ran the code I just tried 2+2, then I started entering stuff like (((8-3)+(7*4)/2)). It doesn't matter what equation you type in, it all outputs 78 as the answer

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here but where are the values copied from `equ` to the `math` array

Comment: Instead of creating that `math` array why not just loop through the values in `equ`? `std::string` has an `[]` operator overload.

Answer (score 0):

OK So I didn't go through everything with a fine toothed combed, but one obvious issue is that the `char` values from `equ` are never copied into the `math` array.

Below I just removed the C style `math` array and instead loop through the `char` values in `equ` (I renamed the `equ` variable to `math`).

Also note I only tested this with 5*5, I did not do any further testing beyond that.

```
/** Removed for brevity**/

int main( )
{
    string math{ "5*5" };
    //cout << "Enter an expression: ";
    //getline(cin, math);
    stack<char> s;
    stack<int> op_s;

    for ( auto i = 0; i < math.size( ); i++ )
    { 
        if( math[ i ] == '(' )
        {
            s.push( '(' );
        }
        else if(math[ i ] == ')')
        {
            while( s.top( ) != '(' )
            {
                int r = op_s.top();
                op_s.pop();
                int l = op_s.top();
                op_s.pop();
                int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
                op_s.push(re);
                s.pop();
             }
             s.pop();
         }
         else if(math[i] == '+' || math[i] == '-' || math[i] == '*' || math[i] == '/' || math[i] == '^')
         {
             int pC = pri(math[i]);
             while(!s.empty() && pri(s.top()) >= pC)
             {
                 int r = op_s.top();
                 op_s.pop();
                 int l = op_s.top();
                 op_s.pop();
                 int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
                 op_s.push(re);
                 s.pop();
              }
              s.push(math[i]);
          }
          else
          {
              op_s.push(int( math[ i ] ) - 48 );
          }
      }
      while(!s.empty())
      {
           int r = op_s.top();
           op_s.pop();
           int l = op_s.top();
           op_s.pop();
           int re = calculate(s.top(),l,r);
           op_s.push(re);
           s.pop();
       }

   cout <<"Result: " << op_s.top() << endl;
   return 0;
}
```